# How to get combination of combinations in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Here I have a dataset with transactions. Each transaction could have 1+ different values - 'dimensions'. Values could not be the same per transaction. I want to create a dataframe with 'dimensions' in the columns and in lines, and count how many times one dimension was used together with another per transaction.

Here what I tried

```
dim_set = [ (1, 'Customer group$Large'),
        (1, 'DEPARTMENT$Sales'),
        (2, 'Customer group$Medium'),
        (2, 'DEPARTMENT$Sales'),
        (3, 'DEPARTMENT$Sales'),
        (4, 'Customer group$Small'),
        (4, 'DEPARTMENT$Sales')
        ]
df = pd.DataFrame(dim_set, columns=['combination_id', 'dimension'])
df
```

[image]

```
df_st_1 = df.pivot_table(index = 'dimension', columns = 'dimension',values = 'combination_id', aggfunc = 'count')
df_st_1
```

an expected result should be like this

```
dim_set = [ ('Customer group$Large', 1, 1, 0, 0),
        ('DEPARTMENT$Sales', 1, 4, 1, 1),
        ('Customer group$Medium', 0, 1, 1, 0),
        ('Customer group$Small', 0, 1, 0, 1)
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(dim_set, columns=['dimension','Customer group$Large', 'DEPARTMENT$Sales', 'Customer group$Medium', 'Customer group$Small'])
df
```

[image]

Comment: use itertools for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), last some data cleaning by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = df.merge(df, on='combination_id', suffixes=('','_'))
df1 = (pd.crosstab(df1['dimension'], df1['dimension_'])
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None)
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df1)
               dimension  Customer group$Large  Customer group$Medium  \
0   Customer group$Large                     1                      0   
1  Customer group$Medium                     0                      1   
2   Customer group$Small                     0                      0   
3       DEPARTMENT$Sales                     1                      1   

   Customer group$Small  DEPARTMENT$Sales  
0                     0                 1  
1                     0                 1  
2                     1                 1  
3                     1                 4
```